# How to implement jwt token and save data using multiple axios request in react

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

if user gives email and password . it will give  input: {token:"asdfasd", auth: 'auth"} . if  user is authorized, it will call second api gives a amount of data , otherwise , it will return unauth

Initially, I get two data first time , but When I refresh, I didn't see my second data in reducers and My auth is unauthorized.

```
compententDidmount(){
 this.props.loginuser()
}

export const loginUser = userData => dispatch => {

axios
 .get('/api/users/login', params:{userdata:userdata})
 .then(res => {

  // Save to localStorage
  const { token } = res.data;

  // Set token to ls
  localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', token);

  // Set token to Auth header
  setAuthToken(token);

  // Decode token to get user data
  const decoded = jwt_decode(token);

  // Set current user
  dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));

  if(res.data.authorized === "authorized"){

   axios.get('2nd api', {params:{user:userdata.email}}).then(res=> {

    console.log(res.data) //authorized
})} else {
      console.log(res.data) // unauthorized }
})};

// Check for token
if (localStorage.jwtToken) {

// Set auth token header auth

setAuthToken(localStorage.jwtToken);

// Decode token and get user info and exp

const decoded = jwt_decode(localStorage.jwtToken);

// Set user and isAuthenticated
store.dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));}
```

I need to get two data when I refresh the browser . How can I solve this?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to do can you tell us what your input and output are supposed to be?

Comment: if user gives email and password . it will give  input: {token:"asdfasd", auth: 'auth"} . if  user is authorized, it will call second api gives a amount of data , otherwise , it will return unauth

Comment: you've got a nested promise... so how do you expect nested async promises to resolve?